# Locking workstation or user switching

Tags: winapi

I 've been using LockWorkstation API to lock the workstation, however this only works in my Windows 7 laptop.

In my Win 8.1 desktop, this function does nothing. Can I go programmatically to the "switch user" screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can display the "switch user" screen with the following code:

```
WTSDisconnectSession(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, WTS_CURRENT_SESSION, FALSE);
```

Note that [`WTSDisconnectSession`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383830(v=vs.85).aspx) is only available for Vista and up, so if you need XP compatibility you would have to use `GetProcAddress` rather than calling the function directly.